# Multiple user accounts in Safari like in Chrome?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

> **Note:** creating a separate **system** user is not an option for me.

In Google Chrome, I can create separate "users" and launch a new Chrome window. Tabs that are opened in this window have their own sessions (cookie jars) that I can keep separate from other user's sessions.

This is great for me because, as a developer, I have personal and work "users" with separate logins for many of the same services.

E.g., I have a personal and a work gmail account - instead of combining them in gmail, I prefer to keep them separate. In my personal Chrome window, I login to gmail to read personal email. In my work Chrome window, I login to gmail (Google Apps for your domain) to read work email.

Another common one is digitalocean, github, and bitbucket. I have personal accounts for each, and work accounts for each. Keeping these things in separate Chrome windows is very helpful for me.

Another great thing about it is Chrome will save my tabs for me. When I'm at work, I can close my personal user window and open my work user window. All of my tabs from the last time I was working will be there. When I'm done with work, I open my personal user window and all my personal tabs are restored.

That said, Chrome is a bloated pig and hogs my RAM and battery. On a brand new Macbook Pro, with Chrome running, I'll get around 4 hours of battery life. With it closed, I can get much closer to 8 hours.

I'd like to ditch Chrome and try Safari, but without such a user profile feature, I'm afraid it will not be useful for me. If it's not natively possible, is there a plugin/extension available?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 15):

I, too, have looked for this ability in Safari, but it just doesn't exist. I've submitted an enhancement request at Apple's [Safari Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) page every time a new version has come out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I submitted a feature request.

Comment: It's that time of the year again, I hope you submitted your feedback, I did :)

Answer (score 11):

SwitchUp is no longer actively supported, unfortunately but I have a recommendation which I am using just now –

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Run a second safari :-) Technically, this would be beta software so you may run into issues, but it's the closest I can see to accomplishing this (and yes, you'd only be limited to 2 profiles with this).

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't really help much, since bookmarks are shared between blue safari (standard) and purple safari (tech preview). If you want to have two completely separate identities this doesn't help.

Comment: I like it, that everything is still shared, like iCloud tabs, etc. But that's definitely up to personal preference/needs. For me this is a really awesome workaround!

Comment: Nice. This should work great for me. Appreciate it!

Comment: Running Safari Technology Preview as a workaround to get a separate user profile is a great tip. The "cookie jar" for different accounts is the biggest win for me. I like shared bookmarks between accounts and I actually end up using Pinboard.in for things I really want to remember later.

Answer (score 2):

Open another tab in private browsing. It lets me log into one tab with my own Facebook, and another tab as my wife's Facebook.

Comment: Useful for many cases, but many sites (e.g. Netflix) won't run in private browsing at all. Plus you might want your history etc.

Comment: Or different sets of passwords, bookmarks, extension configurations, privacy settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SwitchUp is a solution for you. I'm using it for some time now and I like it.

[SwitchUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/switchup/) makes it easy to create separate profiles so you can use an application for both home and work with different accounts, settings and data. It's like a multi-user environment for every application.

Not only for Safari but also for other apps :-) Although you can use it only for Safari...

Comment: Can we use all the profile at the same time with SwitchUp, like in Chrome?